# JTable column display problem using rs2xml

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The column from my database do not show , i only get the rows with correct data but no column headers . does someone know the answer to this problem? thank you

```
public class interftable extends JFrame {

private static JFrame frame;
public static JButton valider;
public JTable jt ;
public static JPanel panel;

public interftable() {

    JTable jt = new JTable();
    jt.setBounds(20, 20, 700, 400);

    JFrame frame= new JFrame(); 
    frame.setSize(800,500);
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(800, 500);
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(20, 20, 700, 400);
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    
    frame.add(jt);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    try {
```

////database connection

```
        Class c = Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Driver pilote = (Driver)c.newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(pilote);
        
        String conString ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/user";
        String nomConnexion = "root";
        String motDePasse = "123";
        Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(conString,nomConnexion,motDePasse);
        

        String sql="select * from users ";
        Statement smt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery(sql);

        jt.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {}

        frame.add(jt);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

//main

```
public static void main (String[]args) {
                interftable f=new interftable();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setBounds(20, 20, 700, 400);
frame.add(scrollPane);

frame.add(jt);
```

Frist of all don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

So get rid of all the setBounds() statements. In this simple example the scrollpane/table will be added to the BorderLayout.CENTER, which means it will fill the entire frame.

If you want the header to be displayed, then the table must be added to a JScrollPane.

Your code should be:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jt);
//scrollPane.setBounds(20, 20, 700, 400);
frame.add(scrollPane);

//frame.add(jt);
```

Also don't know why you repeat this code again:

```
    frame.add(jt);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Get rid of it.

You should not add the table to the frame. It only belongs in the scrollpane.
Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for the basics of using a JTable. You should understand the basics before you attempt to use a database and a 3rd part class to create the TableModel.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.